# Firebase Cloud Messaging -> Illegal State Exception in Android

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make an app based on Cordova that is able to send Notifications via FireBase Cloud Messaging

Here the MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(this,NotificationService.class);
    startService(i);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    Helper mhelper=new Helper(this,appView);
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Testing");
        Log.d("Message","Subscribed To Testing");


    Log.d("Token",FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
    loadUrl(launchUrl);


}
}
```

However I am getting a Illegal State Exception at Line 49:

```
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Testing");
```

The rest Manifest.xml etc. are the same as the sample provided here
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

In the Logcat, the error it is showing is::

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: careerage.jobseeker.app, PID: 5764
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{careerage.jobseeker.app/careerage.jobseeker.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at careerage.jobseeker.app.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
                                                                       at careerage.jobseeker.app.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                                                                       at careerage.jobseeker.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:0)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried [java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346363/java-lang-illegalstateexception-firebaseapp-with-name-default)
 but still it doesn't recognize FirebaseDatabase Class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346363/java-lang-illegalstateexception-firebaseapp-with-name-default

Comment: @USKMobility I tried that too. But I am not using Firebase Database. So there isn't any class present in my library

Comment: I am not an expert in Cordova and its build system, but firebase sdk requires gradle androidmanifest-merge feature to add extra components (defined in the firebase libraries) to your androidmanifest.xml file.
Can you check that your final AndroidManifest includes a content-provider created by Firebase ?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I think Fcm and Gcm take some time to get tokens.. If I try to do anything with cloud messaging without the token being assigned I will get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Fcm and Gcm take some time to get tokens.. If you try to do anything with cloud messaging without the token being assigned you will get error.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your dependency to:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
```

This bug was fixed in patches between 9.0.0 and 9.0.2