# java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name project already exists?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am using firebase in my android project but when I run the app on real device I am getting the following exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name project already exists!
what I have tried  I already tried all stackoverflow answer but it did not solve my problem I have tried even  the following link as well
[FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186425/firebaseapp-name-default-already-exists)

below is my kotlin where I have initialized firebase in my MainActivity.kt kotlin code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        appCommon.initKey(applicationContext)
        val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("Application Id") // Required for Analytics.
            .setProjectId("Project Id") // Required for Firebase Installations.
            .setApiKey("Api key") // Required for Auth.
            .build()
        initializeApp(applicationContext, options, "project id")
```

I want to know where exactly I am making the problem

Comment: Is there a specific reason why are you manually initializing Firebase? Firebase should already be initialized once you [add the google-services plugin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file) to your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  fixed issue  I have added a new ssh key from Google cloud console to firebase  and I updated the google json api key  then it worked