# Flutter - FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

Tags: firebase, flutter, fingerprint

I'm working on a flutter application using firebase authentication system and Firestore. I worked for 3 months and I didn't encounter this error before. Now I published my application on play store and I found this error also for debug version with the emulator. I think to have configured properly the system because firebase worked for a while.
I think that this error occurs for all the apk that I builded after the upgrade of flutter.

Some suggestion to solve my problem?
Thanks

I enter my bundle ID on firebase and download the google-service.json file, copy and paste on android/app folder and build. I also tried to clean (as mentioned here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28003 )  and build the project and to enter some SHA1 and SHA-256 fingerprints to try if it was this the problem but I'm not sure which SHA1 enter on firebase.  ReDownloaded the google-service.json and clean - build the project.

Other codes to initialise the FirebaseApp seems pretty old and I don't think that it can work for me like here ([java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346363/java-lang-illegalstateexception-firebaseapp-with-name-default)) .

I just authenticate a user using this code

```
      user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
```

and do some try catch to manage the output.

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.1.1"
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.luxywebdesign.pocketstcw"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("my-release-key.keystore")
            storePassword "StorePassword"
            keyAlias "KeyAlias"
            keyPassword "Password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
  firebase_storage:

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: 0.8.2
  file_picker: ^1.3.3
  firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1
  firebase_core: 0.3.1+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.7
  permission_handler: ^2.2.0
  path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  url_launcher: ^5.0.2
  open_file: ^2.0.1+2
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^0.1.8
  share:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/d-silveira/flutter-share.git
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+1
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  flutter_keychain: ^1.0.0
  pdf: ^1.3.7
  image: ^2.0.7
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.6.1
  auto_size_text: ^2.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1
```

Error message :

```
D/FirebaseApp(23461): Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
```

at the start after the installation of the apk and ...

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461): java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:280)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.getAuth(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:76)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:108)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:222)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:96)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:643)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth(23461):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you didn't make right the configuration settings. make sure to follow these steps :

1. Add your google-service.json file
2. Add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` (app-level grade)
3. Add `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` (app-level grade)
4. Add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'` (project-level gradle)

After all this steps your problem should be solved. I also had the same problem once then I realise I didn't add step 2. Good Luck!